# Why does my .data function work in pieChart but not in lineChart in dc.js?

Tags: javascript, undefined, dc.js

I want to plot data for a dimension that's not in crossfilter so I'm forced to use .data.

All is fine for a pieChart, but when I switch to a lineChar I get the error `p is undefined` (Firefox) or `Cannot read property y of undefined` (Chrome). I tried following the code, but got a little lost in it. Can you tell me where it's going wrong?

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script>    
    dc.barChart("#test")
        .width(100).height(100)
        .dimension({})
        .group({})
        .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,5]))
        .data(function(){
            return [ 
                {key : 0, value : 4},
                {key : 2, value : 14},
                {key : 3, value : 20},
            ];
        });

    dc.renderAll();
</script>
```

The code works if you do a `pieChart`, and comment out `.x`.

Here's a jsfiddle, note that the scripts are loaded from rawgit.com: http://fiddle.jshell.net/fyy5m26r/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you aren't going to be able to use `.data()` with bar or line charts with a reasonable amount of effort, because [dc.js uses .data() internally](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/584) and in this case you would have to call `d3.stack` yourself in order to create the data it is expecting.

Instead, I suggest you create a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-filter-the-data-before-its-charted). You can do this inline by using

```
.group({all: function() { ... }})
```

instead of

```
.data(function() {...})
```

Or, with your example code:

```
dc.barChart("#test")
    .width(200).height(200)
    .dimension({})
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0,5]))
    .group({all: function(){
        return [ 
            {key : 0, value : 4},
            {key : 2, value : 14},
            {key : 3, value : 20},
        ];
    }});
```

Fork of your fiddle here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gordonwoodhull/4Lf8n7pn/8/